# Make text not wrap around icon in :before pseudoelement?

Tags: css, css-selectors, icons, pseudo-element

I have an icon in a :before pseudoelement, and if the textelement becomes to long and goes to the next row, I want it to not wrap around my pseudoelement but keep it's distance.

Here is a link to my example:
http://jsbin.com/yosevagaqa/1/edit?html,css,output

If you resize the window so that the text is forces into a new line, you can see the problem.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: If the size of the square in `:before` is always the same, one solution would be to add `.link {margin-left:25px; text-indent:-25px;}` to the CSS. http://jsbin.com/meluhapeje/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: OK, I've written it up an an answer. With some other alternatives to choose from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from the other answers, there are multiple solutions!

If the size of the square in `:before` is always the same, one other solution would be to add

```
.link {margin-left:25px; text-indent:-25px;}
```

to the CSS. This causes the entire block to be shifted to the right, except for the first line, containing the square, which gets "outdented".

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3xbfyqkh/

Or what I would prefer, with sizes in `em`s, so that the red square depends on the font size.

```
.link:before {
  /* .. */
  width: 1em; height: 1em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.link {margin-left:1.5em; text-indent:-1.5em;}
```

Making sure, of course, that the indentation is the same as the size + the margin of the square.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3xbfyqkh/1/

Another approach, since the purpose is to make a custom "bullet", would be to treat the `h5` like a list item. Then you won't need the `::before` trick. You will need other tricks to make the square the right size though...

```
.link {
    display:list-item; list-style:square;
    color:red;
    font-size:2em; line-height:.5em;
    margin:.5em 0 .5em 1em}

.link a {
    font-size:.417em; vertical-align:.3em}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3xbfyqkh/5/

Answer (score 3):

You can add following CSS:

```
.link{
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.link{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.link:before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="link"><a href="#">A long link that might wrap and then it gets all weird and stuff</a></h5>
```